# Does Atmega-2560 support image processing capability?

Tags: arduino-mega, signal-processing

As the title says **can I perform image processing on Atmega-2560?**
Basically I have to capture real time images and detect green or red color.
I have not thought of the frame rate but it is not that fast or slow.

Comment: How large images? What type of image processing operations? How fast; frame rate etc. In general - no.

Comment: @MikaelPatel I have updated the question.Thank you

Comment: Please give numbers. You may as well ask if a bus with an unspecified number of seats can carry an unspecified number of passengers an unspecified distance in an unspecified time. For example: 1024 x 768 pixels, in 24-bit RGB, at 30 FPS. Do you need to detect exact green? A range? What if green and red are mixed? Do you want to detect if there is a single pixel of red, or more than one?

Answer (score 3):

No. Your question really is: Can an 8-bit processor, running at 16 MHz, with 8 KB of RAM, do image processing at an acceptable rate? Unless you are talking about 10 pixels by 10 pixels, at a frame rate of 1 frame per second, then I doubt it.

You may want to ask the "real" question. See [The X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). There are sensors around that detect colours. If you are making a maze-following robot that needs to stop if it gets near to a red wall, that is a much more achievable objective.